# Funky behavior when animating rotation of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, image-rotation

I'm trying to rotate an UIImageView with the following code:

```
var x = -((self.needleImage.frame.size.width/2) - 15) //x for rotation point

UIView.animateWithDuration(5.0, delay: 10.0, options: nil, animations: {
    var transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x, 0)
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, CGFloat(-M_PI_2))
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -x, 0)
    self.needleImage.transform = transformm
```

The end position is right, but during the animation/rotation, the image is shifted a little to the left before settling at the right place.

I tried the same code with a UIView from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27660878/3355464) and it doesn't do that.

Then I tried wrapping the Imageview inside a View and rotating that, but that didn't help either.

I have drawn a cicle ontop of the rotation point to check if it isn't in the right place, but it seems alright.

Comment: Bonus info: The more i rotate the bigger the shift is.

Comment: Maybe the center axis is not perfectly in center? That would cause almost a "spiral" that would grow larger with more rotations.

Comment: can you elaborate on that? how can i check that?

Comment: So when you take the width and half it, that should be the dead center of x. But you have an offset of 15 points, which may be part of the problem. Have you tried it with just width/2?

Comment: Ye, i tried that, same problem :(

Comment: Maybe Y is off center? You could give my answer a try, maybe it can shed some light.

Comment: I tried your answer real fast, but didn't seem to help :( I think i need to get my eyes off of it and get a fresh view tomorrow :) Ill give your solution another go then :) But thanks so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this code snippet in the past to rotate a view perpetually, but by removing the last closure it should work to rotate an image 360 degrees. This can be adjusted, or course. Right now it's set to 2PI. You'll have to convert your rotation angle to radians.

```
func animateRotator() {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.rotator.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.rotator.transform, CGFloat(M_PI_2))
            }) { (finished) -> Void in
                self.animateRotator()
        }
    }
```